# How to handle a lightlike metric with cross terms, and its corresponding proper time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, causality

I understand that the metric of null-separated events is $\mathrm{d}s^2 = 0$. This would mean that the time component is equal to the spatial components, $\mathrm{d}t^2 = dl^2$.

1. If there are cross terms involved, e.g.
   $\mathrm{d}s^2 = -A \mathrm{d}t^2 + B\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x + C\mathrm{d}x^2 + \cdots $,
   can/should I diagonalize the metric first, in order to cleanly separate the time and spatial components? Otherwise, what other options do I have to proceed?
2. I am not sure I am convinced how proper time works with a lightlike world line. If I can separate the time and spatial components, is it then just a matter of saying $\mathrm{d}\tau^2 = \mathrm{d} l^2$ (that is, replacing the diagonalized time component with $\tau$)? If I cannot separate the time and spatial components, what should I expect to end up with?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here, at least in terminology.   If $\mathrm d\mathbf s=(\mathrm dx^0,\mathrm dx^1,\mathrm dx^2,\mathrm dx^3)$ is an infinitesimal displacement along a null worldline, then $\mathrm ds^2 \equiv \mathbf g(\mathrm d\mathbf s,\mathrm d\mathbf s) = g_{\mu\nu} \mathrm dx^\mu \mathrm dx^\nu = 0$.  This is not really a statement about the metric $\mathbf g$, but rather about the infinitesimal displacement $\mathrm d\mathbf s$.

1. Proceed with what?  You can choose coordinates in which the metric is diagonal if you wish, but whether that's the right thing to do depends on what you're *trying* to do.
2. The proper time along a null worldline is zero by definition $(\mathrm d\tau^2 = 0)$, so you can't use it to parameterize the curve.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I do know that but I need to be more precise in my terminology. 

2. This is my bottleneck in understanding right now. If I am given a photon which takes proper time $d\tau$ to traverse some length $dl$, and let's say I need to find the displacement $dl$, then I am not sure how to connect all of this information together. So now I know that $ds^2 = 0$, $d t^2 = d l^2$, and $d \tau ^2 = 0$. But the spatial distance traversed by the photon can be given by $d l = c d\tau$? So $d l = 0$? Did I get that right? I don't know how to make sense of this.

Comment: @oiolosse "If I am given a photon which takes proper time $\mathrm d\tau$ [$\ldots$]" This is the part which doesn't make sense.  Proper time is a quantity which can be associated to a timelike curve.  It measures the time elapsed by an ideal clock whose worldline is the curve in question.  It would make sense to say that the photon takes *coordinate time* $\mathrm dt$ to traverse a spatial distance $\mathrm d\ell$ in some reference frame, and that $\mathrm d\ell = c \mathrm dt$ - implying that $d\tau^2=c^2dt^2-d\ell^2 = 0$.

Comment: Right, so there is no notion of "proper time" for photons. That makes sense! Then (1), if there were cross terms such that $d\tau ^2 = c^2 dt^2 - B dt dl - dl^2$, and again let's say I need to find displacement $dl$, how would I handle the presence of the cross terms? My first instinct (and the only approach I am aware of at the moment) would be to get rid of them, but are there alternative ways to handle the cross terms and obtain $dl$?

Comment: @oiolosse It's still not entirely clear to me what you mean by obtaining $\mathrm d\ell$.  If $d\tau^2=c^2dt^2-Bdt dx - dx^2$ (so spacetime is 1+1-dimensional), setting $\mathrm d\tau^2=0$ and dividing by $\mathrm dt^2$ would yield $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + B \frac{dx}{dt} = c^2$. This tells you that for a photon trajectory, the rate of change of the coordinate $x$ with respect to the coordinate $t$ depends on which direction the photon is moving.  This seems weird, but it's an artifact of a strange choice of coordinate system.  See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/618338/156895.

Comment: I think I see what is going on now. I will need time to digest everything, but so far, your answers have really helped me. Thank you very much for your time and explanations!